# Accessing Nested Parent Properties

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I believe this is a relatively basic feature of SQL, but unfortunately I'm not managing to think of exactly how it's done, or what it would be called.

Basically, in my current database, we have Areas, which are parts of Districts, which are parts of Zones, which make up a Region.

Along this chain, each parent only has the ID of the next parent, however, I would like to generate a table with all Areas, where every Area has columns for the ID of the District, Zone, and Region of which it's part of. So how would I write this query?

Comment: Yeah, I just realized how rusty I really am. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Laurence(in the comments) responded correctly, I've been out of the SQL game for a bit too long it seems.

So the simple answer would be:

```
SELECT child.id as ChildID, parent.id as ParentID, grandparent.id as GrandparentID
FROM child JOIN parent JOIN grandparent
WHERE child.parentID = parent.id AND parent.parentID = grandparent.id
```

Thanks to all who didn't hardcore downvote this terrible question.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle offers hierarchical querying, where you can say something like

```
 SELECT parent, child, LEVEL 
   FROM table
  START WITH parent IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR child = parent
```

The `START WITH` condition identifies the root of the hierarchy, and the `CONNECT BY PRIOR` clause identifies how to traverse the hierarchy.

MySQL doesn't have this capability, unfortunately.